# NSDictionary issue in IOS6?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdictionary, xcode5

Facing Strange issue when i am trying to call next Class my app crashed in **IOS6** only when i tested my app in IOS5 and IOS7 its working fine .Crash screen shot

[image]

When i googled this issue i got the following  [Solutions](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=%27NSInvalidArgumentException%27,%20reason:%20%27***%20-%5BNSDictionary%20initWithObjects:forKeys:%5D:%20count%20of%20objects%20%280%29%20differs%20from%20count%20of%20keys%20%283%29%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=Lpt-UvyzM4aP5AShuoDwDA#q=Terminating%20app%20due%20to%20uncaught%20exception%20%27NSInvalidArgumentException%27,%20reason:%20%27***%20-%5BNSDictionary%20initWithObjects:forKeys:%5D:%20count%20of%20objects%20%280%29%20differs%20from%20count%20of%20keys%20%283%29%27&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official) but single one did not help me to Resolve my problem.

here is my code where it is Crashing

```
-(IBAction)notesMethod{
NotesClass *notes = [[NotesClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotesClass" bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:notes animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSArray *arrTemp1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Single Event Probability", @"Mutiple Event Probability",@"Permutation", @"Combination",nil];

NSArray *arrTemp2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bionomial Distribution",@"Negativ Bionomial Distribution",@"Hypergeometric Distribution",@"Comulative Hypergeometric Distribution",@"Poission Distribution",@"Multinomial Distribution",nil];

NSArray *arrTemp3 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Uinform Distribution",@"Exponential Distribution",@"Gamma Distribution",@"Gamma Function", @"Beta Distribution", @"Beta Function", @"Standard Normal Distribution",@"PDF of Normal Distribution", @"Z-Table", nil];

NSDictionary *temp =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arrTemp2,@"Discreet Probability Distribution",arrTemp3,@"Continuouse Probability Distribution",arrTemp1,@"Probability",nil];
 }
```

Before presenting the next view my app get Crashed.
when i read about **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT** its all about xib issue,i am sure there is no problem in my xib file.

Crash output

```
StatisticCal[3091:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (3)'
 *** First throw call stack:
```

(0x1886012 0x1439e7e 0x1891737 0xe456d6 0xe6af79 0xe6c507 0xe43c85 0xe6af79 0xe69e97 0xeb67c1 0xf688d3 0xe6af79 0xe69e97 0x4b78c4 0xe6af79 0xe69e97 0x59d648 0xe6af79 0xe6c507 0xe43c85 0xe6af79 0xe69e97 0x59caa3 0x461e37 0x462418 0x462648 0x462882 0x46e235 0x66d3d2 0x46b4f3 0x46b777 0x184cb 0x144d705 0x384920 0x5c0b24 0x144d705 0x384920 0x3848b8 0x445671 0x445bcf 0x444d38 0x3b433f 0x3b4552 0x3923aa 0x383cf8 0x16d0df9 0x16d0ad0 0x17fbbf5 0x17fb962 0x182cbb6 0x182bf44 0x182be1b 0x16cf7e3 0x16cf668 0x38165c 0x6fbc 0x6f55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

any suggestion will be appreciated.thanks

Comment: Have you fixed all compiler warnings? Run Analyzer in Xcode and fixed any warnings? Are you using ARC?

Answer (score 1):

Error message:

> StatisticCal[3091:c07] ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[NSDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:]: **count of objects (0) differs from count
>   of keys (3)**'

The number of objects and keys when creating a dictionary are not the same. That should help you find the error.

This could also me a memory issue where you are accessing a released object. Released objects are not immediately overwritten and when the reuse occurs can be random which would explain why sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Add an exception breakpoint, when it is hit continue to get more information. To add the breakpoint select breakpoints in the Navigator select breakpoints, click on the "+" in the lower left of the Xcode window, select "Add Exception Breakpoint".

As an aside, here is a nice way to format your data (just playing here):

```
NSArray *arrTemp1 = @[@"Single Event Probability",
                      @"Mutiple Event Probability",
                      @"Permutation",
                      @"Combination"];

NSArray *arrTemp2 = @[@"Bionomial Distribution",
                      @"Negativ Bionomial Distribution",
                      @"Hypergeometric Distribution",
                      @"Comulative Hypergeometric Distribution",
                      @"Poission Distribution",
                      @"Multinomial Distribution"];

NSArray *arrTemp3 = @[@"Uinform Distribution",
                      @"Exponential Distribution",
                      @"Gamma Distribution",
                      @"Gamma Function",
                      @"Beta Distribution",
                      @"Beta Function",
                      @"Standard Normal Distribution",
                      @"PDF of Normal Distribution",
                      @"Z-Table"];

NSDictionary *temp = @{@"Probability"                          : arrTemp1,
                       @"Discreet Probability Distribution"    : arrTemp2,
                       @"Continuouse Probability Distribution" : arrTemp3};
```

Comment: i have written code according to your way sir ,but still it crashing.let me test it in Anlayzer.

Comment: My code formatting does not fix anything, just another way to write code that may be more readable.